# Javascript function to convert Javascript Code to String

Tags: javascript, electron

Any simple function to convert long `javascript code` to `string`?

The `code` parameter of [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) - [WebContents.executeJavaScript(code)](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#webcontentsexecutejavascriptcode) needs to be a string. I want to pass a simple javascript function to all the webpages that the `Browser-Window` loads.

This little line works:

`WebContents.executeJavaScript("console.log('FOO');");`

But it becomes a little more difficult once the code gets longer.

This is one particular code block I want to insert.

```
        var ta_arr = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
        for(var i=0;i<ta_arr.length;i++){
            var ta = ta_arr[i];
            if(ta.hasAttribute("placeholder")){
                ta.setAttribute("data-placeholder",ta.placeholder);
                ta.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
                    if(ta.value.length > 0){
                        ta.removeAttribute("placeholder");
                    }else{
                        ta.placeholder=ta.getAttribute("data-placeholder");
                    }
                },false);
            }
        }
```

The textarea placeholder of my [Browser-Window](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) does not disappear when a user types on it. So instead of putting the code above to my apps source files I want to use `WebContents.executeJavaScript` since it is an `Electron` specific problem.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: not familiar with electron, but seems to me that wrapping the code in a function and calling function might be a good start

Comment: @charlietfl I already tried using a function, it returns an error. http://electron.atom.io/ its like `nw.js/Node-webkit` by GitHub

Comment: @Phylogenesis a function in a tool I am using needs javascript code as a string. I have long codes that would be very difficult to turn into a string so I am asking on SO if someone knows of a simple way to convert `code` to `string`

Comment: It may be possible to use the 'fs' module to read a file containing the code into a string and then pass that string to the executeJavaScript call. If you don't mind putting these snippets in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl

```
<script id="myScript">
  var ta_arr = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    for(var i=0;i<ta_arr.length;i++){
        var ta = ta_arr[i];
        if(ta.hasAttribute("placeholder")){
            ta.setAttribute("data-placeholder",ta.placeholder);
            ta.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
                if(ta.value.length > 0){
                    ta.removeAttribute("placeholder");
                }else{
                    ta.placeholder=ta.getAttribute("data-placeholder");
                }
            },false);
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    var s = document.getElementById('myScript');
    var text = s.textContent;
    console.log(text);
</script>
```